# How to update a row on parent table after child table has been changed

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a simple DB which has two tables, serie and season.
Serie has this structure:

```
create table serie(
  name varchar2(30) not null,
  num_seasons number(2,0),
  launch date,
  constraint pk_serie primary key(name)
);
```

Whereas season has this other structure:

```
create table season(
  name_serie varchar2(30) not null,
  num_season number(2,0) not null,
  launch date not null,
  end date,
  constraint pk_season primary key(name_serie,num_season),
  constraint fk_season foreign key(name_serie) references serie(name),
  constraint check_time check(launch<end)
);
```

For example, for a serie with two seasons (num_seasons=2), it would have in season table two rows, num_season=1 and num_season=2.

I would like the num_seasons column in table serie to be a count of how many rows are in season table with the name of the serie. In fact, I want that column to depend in changes in the season table, if you insert a new season of a serie, increase the num_seasons value by 1.

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: varchar2 doesnt exist in mysql

Comment: varchar2 is Oracle. MySQL is also owned by Oracle Inc, but it's not *the* Oracle DBMS.

Comment: Sounds more like you want a view, rather than storing it on the table, as it depends on another table

Comment: It is Oracle XE, sorry for the misunderstanding.

Comment: Just a small point, that's not relevant to your question, but might be interesting to you - the word 'series' in English is not plural, so there is no word 'serie'; you have 'one series', 'two series', etc.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

**The others answer are simply wrong** since they are telling you to perform an insert using a select to check how many season exists only once (at insert time).

**What it would happens on Update/Delete on season table?**
The answer is obvious, you will have all counter not aligned and the data will be unrielable.

For this purpose you have to modify the `serie` table, in particular:

```
num_season NUMBER(2,0) DEFAULT 0
```

and create some [TRIGGER](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_triggers.htm) on `season` table:

> Triggers are procedures that are stored in the database and are
>   implicitly run, or fired, when something happens.
>
> Traditionally, triggers supported the execution of a PL/SQL block when
>   an INSERT, UPDATE, or DELETE occurred on a table or view. Triggers
>   support system and other data events on DATABASE and SCHEMA. Oracle
>   Database also supports the execution of PL/SQL or Java procedures.

```
CREATE TRIGGER incSeasonNum AFTER INSERT ON season
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE serie SET num_seasons = num_seasons + 1 
  WHERE name = NEW.name_serie;
END
```

Another one in case for any rows deletion:

```
CREATE TRIGGER decSeasonNum AFTER DELETE ON season
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE serie SET num_seasons = num_seasons - 1 
  WHERE name = OLD.name_serie;
END
```

And just to be sure to avoid strange update on serie's name or number:

```
CREATE TRIGGER incDecSeasonNum AFTER UPDATE ON season
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  UPDATE serie SET num_seasons = num_seasons - 1 
  WHERE name = OLD.name_serie;
  UPDATE serie SET num_seasons = num_seasons + 1 
  WHERE name = NEW.name_serie;
END
```

Hope this help.

Comment: A complex scenario of triggers which even supports the modification of the PK of the child table. It should technically work, but in general there should not be a need at all to store the totals, since you can query it real time. Caching the totals could be useful for performance purposes, but building it right away would be called "premature optimization". Moreover, this kind of trigger magic tends to get messy. It's better to build a business object in a data layer of the application that makes sure the total is kept in sync when the seasons are modified.

Comment: I agree with you but the question is not "what's better between these approaches" or "does it is correct". Usually this scenario will never happens since `SELECT COUNT` would solve the problem but the scenario is not explained so the response is this... If he need to update the field automatically trigger is the solution!

Answer (score 0):

You can get the number of seasons using a sub-select. No need to store it in serie at all. You could make a view for this.

If you store the seasons anyway, storing the number of seasons is redundant information. You should avoid storing redundant information unless for specific performance reasons.

```
SELECT
  s.name,
  ( SELECT count(*) 
    FROM season ss 
    WHERE ss.name_serie = s.name) as season_count
FROM
  serie s
```

Comment: This answer doesn't solve the user question. The problem of the user is not retrieve the number of serie.

Comment: It does. I suggested not to store the redundant information at all, which is also a possible solution and doesn't require the presence of triggers to keep any data in sync. Please read the actual content before downvoting other answers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert into table `serie` then do as below :

```
INSERT INTO serie (name,num_seasons,launch)
SELECT 
    name_serie
    ,COUNT(num_season)
    ,launch
FROM season
GROUP BY name_serie,launch
;
```

Comment: This answer is simply wrong since the data will be unreliable in case of update/delete on serie's table.

Answer (score 0):

You should maybe review your model.

First you have the serie table where the primary key is the name. Which is not a good idea because the name is text and can change. Better is to set up an Id and the name as another field. Keep information related to the serie in serie and season in season.

Maybe what you need is another table called let's say episodes!

The order a serie is composed by seasons which are composed by episodes.
If you have many to many relatioship you need to add relation tables like serie_season and season_episodes. Then you can count esaily the number of season and episodes for each serie.

Comment: In fact that model that you propose is what I have, but I thought that would be easier to explain the problem just with this two tables. Because if I know how to count seasons I know how to count episodes. Thank you anyway :)

Comment: The idea of a field counting the number of season in serie table is not a good idea. It should be calculated dynamically. What if the trigger is disabled during a certain period of time in your database lifetime? Count is gonna be worg/unsync

Comment: That makes sense too. There isn't only one solution for a problem.